# Hitting line dartboard?

Tags: probability

Assume that a beginner hits a dartboard.
What is the probability that you exactly hit the border line between 13 and 6?

We were thinking that the probability is zero because the probability of somewhere hitting the dartboard is a continuous probability, so then it doesn't matter whether we include the boundary line or not?

We found somewhere else on this site the following: It is possible that the dart hits a point on the diagonal, and it is also conceivable that it lands exactly on the point with coordinates (1e,1π). But as soon as you try to weigh this possibility by some number p≥0 which you then would call the chance or probability of such an event you would quickly realize that the only value for p that leads to coherent consequences is p=0.

We do not know how we can try to weigh the possibility by some number p>=o and come to the conclusion that p=0.

We hope that you can explain this to us.

Edit:
Should we say something like: if we consider points to have positive probability, we have infinitely many points on the dartboard all with positive probabilities and those probabilities can never sum up to only one? So a point has zero probability. But what do we say about a line then?

Comment: It depends how fat the dividing wire is ... and how big the tip of the dart is.

Comment: Think of a ball $B$ in $\mathbb R^2$ having area 1. If $A\subseteq B$ then the probability that $A$ is 'hit' corresponds with the area of $A$. If $A$ is some line then it has area $0$.

Comment: But what do we conclude from this? We also think that a line has area zero.

Comment: Yes, a set of points that form a line has no area and hence the probability of hitting it is 0.